How to reproduce tab completion of properties for generic psobjects on the pipeline in a custom function?
If I type onto the command line:
[pscustomobject]@{ name = 'test'; description='doing test' } | Select-Object

I can press tab and complete the property names—besides the default properties, either of the defined properties name and description. Select-Object is aware of the name and description properties on the input object and will autocomplete them with standard tab behavior.
Now if I use a custom function, such as:
function pipeobject {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        $InputObject,

        [Parameter(Position=0)]
        $Property
    )

    process {
        $Property | Foreach-Object { $InputObject.$_ }
    }
}

and enter:
[pscustomobject]@{ name = 'test'; description='doing test' } | pipeobject 

I cannot tab complete the -Property parameter for any of the properties on the input object.
Note: I am aware of this reply which recommends using output types. However, my inquiry refers to parsing the properties of a generic pscustomobject, which Select-Object seems capable of.
Question
How can I reproduce Select-Object's tab completion behavior on the pipeline for properties in my custom functions?

What you're describing, inferring members from a pscustomobject from pipeline, is one of many great tab completion improvements in PowerShell v7.4 from MartinGC94 (PR #18682 in this case) and short answer is you won't find an easy way to replicate what he did in a robust way but to show you how you can approach the problem by looking at the CommandAst should be a start:
Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName pipeobject -ParameterName Property -ScriptBlock {
    param(
        [string] $CommandName,
        [string] $ParameterName,
        [string] $WordToComplete,
        [System.Management.Automation.Language.CommandAst] $CommandAst,
        [System.Collections.IDictionary] $FakeBoundParameters
    )

    $ast = $CommandAst.Parent.FindAll({
        $args[0] -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.ConvertExpressionAst] },
        $true)

    if (-not $ast.Child.KeyValuePairs) {
        return
    }

    $hash = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(
        [System.StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)

    foreach ($item in $ast.Child.KeyValuePairs.Item1) {
        $key = $item.ToString()

        if (-not $hash.Add($key)) {
            continue
        }

        if ($key.StartsWith($WordToComplete, [StringComparison]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
            $item
        }
    }
}



Instead of trying to reimplement all the type inference code yourself, you can simply call the tab completion API to get the results, here's an example:
Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName Remove-Item -ParameterName Include  -ScriptBlock {
    param ($commandName, $parameterName, [string] $wordToComplete, $commandAst, $fakeBoundParameters)

    $CleanWordToComplete = $wordToComplete.Trim('"',"'") + '*'
    $Parent = $commandAst.Parent
    while ($null -ne $Parent.Parent)
    {
        $Parent = $Parent.Parent
    }

    $ScriptText = $Parent.Extent.Text.Remove($commandAst.Extent.StartOffset) + "Select-Object -Property "
    $Res = TabExpansion2 -inputScript $ScriptText -cursorColumn $ScriptText.Length

    foreach ($Item in $Res.CompletionMatches)
    {
        if ($Item.CompletionText.Trim('"',"'") -like $CleanWordToComplete)
        {
            $Item
        }
    }
}

Here I simply go all the way to the top of the AST to get the script text and then replace the command call with Select-Object and call TabExpansion2 with that script text to get the completion results.

Thanks! I had something quite similar to this after your comment on Reddit. This is great stuff to have, appreciate having the examples straight from the architect. I'd like to account for dynamically generated objects as well, such as objects generated in a pipeline like gc file.json | ConvertFrom-Json | <custom function with property completion>. I will probably need to add a control flow where if no properties are found, it runs the CommandAst once, e.g., gc file.json | ConvertFrom-Json | Select -First 1 and then checks the properties.

I don't have any better ideas on how to handle dynamic objects but that seems risky if you aren't careful with the input. I mean what if the previous command or one of the parameters is an expression with side effects (Remove-Item for example)? So be sure to add some validation logic if you want to implement this.

Good point, thanks!
